# SOQL query Join

Tags: soql

I trying build query: 
Start from AuthSession and go to User and then go to PermissionSet.

Maybe someone help me with query (`SELECT Id FROM User.PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId=:UserId AND PermissionSetId = 'xxxxxxx')`

```
SELECT UserId, 
    (SELECT Id 
        FROM 
        User.PermissionSetAssignment 
        WHERE 
        AssigneeId=:UserId AND 
        PermissionSetId = 'xxxxxxx') 
    FROM 
    AuthSession 
    WHERE 
    UserType = 'Customer Portal User'
```

Please lem me know if I wrong thinking.

Comment: Why would you add the `[appcloud]` tag to this question? It may deserve some tags in addition to `[soql]`, but that one does not seem to have anything to do with what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't do a SOQL query on an object called
  "User.PermissionSetAssignment" because that doesn't exist.
- There is no relationship between PermissionSetAssignment and AuthSession.
- The field on AuthSession is UsersId, not UserId.

You will need to make separate queries and the join them using a map or a similar technique.

```
Set<Id> myUsers = new Set<ID>();
for(AuthSession a : [SELECT UsersId FROM AuthSession WHERE UserType = 'Customer Portal User']){
    myUsers.add(a.UsersId);
}

List<PermissionSetAssignment> PSAs = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId IN :myUsers AND PermissionSetId = 'xxxxxxx'];
```

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

This query is one way to do it (assuming you don't have a User Id upfront that you want to filter by but instead want all the matching Users); replace the `?` with the `PermissionSet` field names you want to access:

```
for (PermissionSetAssignment psa : [
        select Id, PermissionSet.?, PermissionSet.?, PermissionSet.?
        from PermissionSetAssignment
        where AssigneeId in (
                select UsersId
                from AuthSession
                where UserType = 'Customer Portal User'
                )
        and PermissionSetId = 'xxxxxxx'
        ]) {
    PermissionSet ps = psa.PermissionSet;
    ...
}
```

This [User, Sharing, and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_users.htm?search_text=authsession) ERD is helpful as is this [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) documentation that includes the atypical field name of `UsersId`.